# To run Azure Function with Timer Trigger using Spring Cloud locally

Tags: spring-boot, azure-functions, spring-cloud

I am trying to create an **Azure Function with Timer Trigger** to schedule a job(locally). I am using **Spring Cloud**. I am not able to create a bean and schedule the trigger. I can`t find a configuration for Spring Cloud to schedule a Timer Trigger. I am not sure what I am **missing**.

My SpringBoot Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Config {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public void startTimer() {
        System.out.println("startTimer begin test");
        TimerTriggerShiftNew ti;        
    }   
}
class TimerTest {

    public void startTimer() {
        System.out.println("startTimer begin");
    }
}
```

My Timer Trigger:

```
public class EmailTimeTrigger{

    @FunctionName("emailtimetrigger")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 */2 * * * *") String timerInfo,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm if you are running your project using `mvn azure-functions:run` as documented in the [Spring Cloud - Azure Functions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure#run-the-function-locally).

Comment: First fix your code: EmailTimeTrigger needs to extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler. in Run method you have to call handleRequest(), startTimer ATBean has to have the very same name as ATFunctionName... but yeah, i have problem to call it event than... )-:

Comment: Please see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743022/1441210

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change your function name from `startTimer` to `emailtimetrigger` as u wrote it in the `@functionName`
and u should add some annotations in your pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.3.4</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
    <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.3.4</azure.functions.java.library.version>
    <functionAppName>spring-azure-function</functionAppName>
    <functionAppRegion>francecentral</functionAppRegion>
    <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
    <functionResourceGroup>spring-azure-function-rg</functionResourceGroup>
    <start-class>com.targa.labs.dev.springfunctionsazure.SpringFunctionsAzureApplication</start-class>
    <wrapper.version>1.0.23.RELEASE</wrapper.version>
</properties>
```

you can find full example [here](https://blog.nebrass.fr/playing-with-spring-cloud-in-azure-functions/)