# Spring cloud function [Azure] TimerTrigger

Tags: azure-functions, spring-cloud

Anybody has Spring cloud Function [Azure] TimerTrigger sample implementation ?Please do share

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this running by doing the following (this is based off the HttpTrigger code):

1. Create the handler that has the TimerTrigger:

```java
@Component
public class TimerHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<User, Greeting> {

    @FunctionName("timedTrigger")
    public void timedTrigger(
            @TimerTrigger(name = "trigger", schedule = "0 */30 * * * *") String timerInfo,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        // We need to invoke the handleRequest so our spring function (defined as a bean) will be invoked.
        Greeting g = handleRequest(new User("Trigger"), context);
    }
}
```

2. Add your bean (with the same name as the function above).

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = "your.package.structure"
)
public class SpringApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TimedHandler.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<User, Greeting> timedTrigger() {        
        return user -> new Greeting("Welcome, " + user.getName());
    }

}
```

3. After you get the base working you can modify the `AzureSpringBootRequestHander` type and the `Function` types.

Comment: In 2022 the Azure functions API has changed. They renamed AzureSpringBootRequestHandler into FunctionInvoker.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in November 2022 the only information we have is:

1. the article [Getting started with Spring Cloud Function in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure)
2. Github code sample [hello-spring-function-azure](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hello-spring-function-azure).
3. Spring Coud docs about [Azure Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/current/reference/html/azure.html)

In all sources they are talking only about one type of invocation for Azure Function: `HttpTrigger`. Other 8 trigger types are ignored. In the spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure library we can see only 2 classes: `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker` and `org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.HttpFunctionInvoker`.

Although we as a developers want to use Spring Boot application to process all kinds of inputs offered by Azure Functions. Seems like it is time to open tickets to Azure Java team to extend code samples to support all types of triggers.

Speaking of TimerTrigger - it is basically scheduled task without input and without output. In Java we use Void when we want to do or use nothing. Unfortunately the FunctionInvoker mentioned above doesn't support funcitons without input or output: it fails with errors. You have to create you handler to extends FunctionInvoker<String, String> and your function to implements Function<Mono, Mono>. You can ignore input and return any string though.

Once you make the sample project (see [2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/hello-spring-function-azure) above) work locally so you able to run your function using `./mvnw azure-funcitons:run` you can add second function and azure handler for it. Here is my example, running every 10 seconds:

**Function:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.function.Function;

import com.example.services.SomeOtherService;

@Component("myScheduledTask")
public class MyScheduledTask implements Function<Mono<String>, Mono<String>> {

    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherService serviceDependency;

    @Override
    public Mono<String> apply(Mono<String> input) {
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++ My task has been triggered ++++++++++++");

        return input.map(s -> {
            System.out.println("input = " + s); //you don't have to do this - it is just example
            // invoking some other methods of the dependent service
            serviceDependency.runMyTask();
            //... here you put some more code
            //... as needed
            return "OK";
        });
    }
}
```

**Handler:**

```
package com.example;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.TimerTrigger;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker;

/**
* This handler invokes my function with name "myScheduledTask" every 10 seconds using Azure TimerTrigger.
*/
public class MyScheduledTaskHandler extends FunctionInvoker<String, String> {

    @FunctionName("myScheduledTask")
    public String runOnSchedule(
            @TimerTrigger(name = "myScheduledTaskTrigger", schedule = "*/10 * * * * * ") String timerInfo,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        // timeInfo is a JSON string, you can deserialize it to an object using your favorite JSON library
        context.getLogger().info("Timer is triggered: " + timerInfo);
        return handleRequest(timerInfo, context);
    }
}
```

Please note that when you run `./mvnw clean package` you should see the following in your logs:

```
[INFO] 2 Azure Functions entry point(s) found.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Step 2 of 8: Generating Azure Functions configurations
[INFO] Generation done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Step 3 of 8: Validating generated configurations
[INFO] Validation done.
```

If it says that it couldn't find Azure Function entry point(s) then something is not set up correctly in your environment or configuration.

I tested it on my Windows 11 running with  `./mvnw azure-functions:run`
and it is working. Here is the piece of log output:

```
[2022-11-01T21:00:00.027Z] Function "myScheduledTask" (Id: 92313ca0-7f4d-4a90-847a-8e9f6d2624d3) invoked by Java Worker
[2022-11-01T21:00:00.027Z] +++++++++++++ My task has been triggered ++++++++++++
[2022-11-01T21:00:00.029Z] Executed 'Functions.myScheduledTask' (Succeeded, Id=92313ca0-7f4d-4a90-847a-8e9f6d2624d3, Duration=11ms)
[2022-11-01T21:00:00.030Z] input = {"Schedule":{"AdjustForDST":true},"ScheduleStatus":null,"IsPastDue":false}
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.006Z] Executing 'Functions.myScheduledTask' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-11-02T00:00:10.0059718+03:00', Id=d8565858-a64e-460f-b639-e2a37c609eef)
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.011Z] 2022-11-02 00:00:10.010  INFO 1328 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.c.function.utils.FunctionClassUtils  : Main class: class com.example.DemoApplication
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.013Z] Timer is triggered: {"Schedule":{"AdjustForDST":true},"ScheduleStatus":null,"IsPastDue":false}
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.013Z] +++++++++++++ My task has been triggered ++++++++++++
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.016Z] input = {"Schedule":{"AdjustForDST":true},"ScheduleStatus":null,"IsPastDue":false}
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.021Z] Function "myScheduledTask" (Id: d8565858-a64e-460f-b639-e2a37c609eef) invoked by Java Worker
[2022-11-01T21:00:10.024Z] Executed 'Functions.myScheduledTask' (Succeeded, Id=d8565858-a64e-460f-b639-e2a37c609eef, Duration=18ms)
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.008Z] Executing 'Functions.myScheduledTask' (Reason='Timer fired at 2022-11-02T00:00:20.0082693+03:00', Id=026a8a91-d6da-4162-bcfe-e58e1618d759)
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.013Z] 2022-11-02 00:00:20.012  INFO 1328 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.c.function.utils.FunctionClassUtils  : Main class: class com.example.DemoApplication
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.015Z] Timer is triggered: {"Schedule":{"AdjustForDST":true},"ScheduleStatus":null,"IsPastDue":false}
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.015Z] +++++++++++++ My task has been triggered ++++++++++++
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.017Z] Function "myScheduledTask" (Id: 026a8a91-d6da-4162-bcfe-e58e1618d759) invoked by Java Worker
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.018Z] input = {"Schedule":{"AdjustForDST":true},"ScheduleStatus":null,"IsPastDue":false}
[2022-11-01T21:00:20.020Z] Executed 'Functions.myScheduledTask' (Succeeded, Id=026a8a91-d6da-4162-bcfe-e58e1618d759, Duration=11ms)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The official Spring TimerTrigger sample is here: [function-sample-azure-time-trigger](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure-time-trigger).
The README should help you build and run it locally or on Azure.
Mind that for local deployment you need an `Azure emulator` and can use the provided docker script.

For further information check the [Spring Cloud Function Azure Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/4.0.5-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/azure.html#_microsoft_azure_functions) documentation and the various [Samples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/4.0.5-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/azure.html#_samples) provided.

Answer (score -1):

This is the sample of httptrigger:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure

you can replace the httptrigger with the timetrigger:

```
@FunctionName("TimerTriggerJava1")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerInfo,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
```

This is you need to import:

```
import java.time.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
```

Comment: httptrigger was already replaced with  timetrigger . But core issue is it's not invoking or delegating the task to spring cloud function (i.e. @Bean TimerTriggerJava1 defined as spring cloud function whose name is same as azure functionName i.e. TimerTriggerJava1.